# C - how to pass structure as a parameter and increment its value

Tags: c, structure

I pass a structure `by val` to hello().
`p.value` is equal to zero , afterwards it get the `p.value++` value
Why Doesn't `p.value` equal to 1 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct pval{
   char *msg;
   unsigned int value;
   unsigned int address;    
};

void hello(struct pval p)
{
  printf("%s %d %d \n", p.msg,p.value++,p.address);
}

int main()
{
 struct pval pval = { "Hello world",0,0 };
 hello(pval);
}
```

Comment: `p.value` does equal `1` after incrementing . It would improve the question to have the program show some output that differs to your expectation

Comment: Try `++p.value`, and then learn the difference between preincrement and postincrement.

Comment: Are you asking about the value of `p.value` in `hello` after the call to `printf`?  There, its value is `1`, but `0` is printed because you used a post-increment.  But the value of `pval.value` in `main` after the call to `hello` is 0, because `pval` was passed by value.

Comment: yes  Thank you to both